# Display tweet using Twitter Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twitter

I should say I'm new to Ruby. I just managed to create a Twitter app and configure The Twitter Ruby Gem to tweet, display tweets and so on. The problem is that when I fetch tweets, the actual content is not displayed, instead, I get somehting like `#<Twitter::Tweet:0x2a3de78>`.

I simply use this code snippet:

```
puts Twitter.status(123456789)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `Twitter.status` method returns an instance of the class [`Twitter::Tweet`](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet).

To extract data from `Twitter::Tweet` you have to call some methods on it, like `text`:

```
puts Twitter.status(...).text
```

Comment: I suspected something along those lines. Thank you!